# Can a non EEA spouse have two Schengen visas (family and tourist)?

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas, multiple-entry

I went to Italy with my husband last year (he is British and I am Indian and we live in the UK). I got a free spouse of an EU national visa for a year with multiple entries allowed, this was issued by the Italian consulate. So technically, I have a valid Schengen visa but in the annotations, it says 'free visa, EU family' (in Italian).

Now I'm going to Spain with my sister in July and my husband can't join us. I know that according to EU law, I should apply for a new tourist visa. But will my existing Schengen Type C tourist visa cause any issues? I have read that you cannot have two Schengen visas at the same time.

I am dreading the thought of getting visas canceled and chasing consulates for a short weekend trip.

My questions are:

1. If I apply for a Schengen visa with the Spanish consulate, will they ask me to cancel my existing Schengen (EU family)?
2. Or should I go to Spain without my husband?

It would help to know if anyone in this situation has been successful at changing their visa types or simply visiting the Schengen area without their spouse.

Comment: I am specifically asking if you can have two Schengen visas at the same time given that one is only valid if you travel with your spouse.

Comment: IMO a Schengen "C" visa is valid for the duration mentioned on the sticker. Anything written in remarks column does not per se affect the validity. This is also stated in the answer of the linked question.

Comment: But why would you apply for a visa if you don't need one in the first place? Marking as a dupe.

Comment: Because of what is stated here: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm It says spouses traveling alone need visas. My only confusion is that the visa I have was given on the basis that my spouse will be traveling with me.

Comment: In the article you point to, I only found a sample story about a residence permit holder who needs a visa to travel alone. You already have a schengen visa with remarks that it is free as you are spouse of an EU national. As linked question already answers, if you have a visa you are good to go as long as you carry proof that you are still married to EU national (marriage certificate and a note from your spouse). For residence cards the linked answer makes no assumtions and says anything can happen.